# How to right align this submit button?

Tags: css

I have a large number for forms with submit buttons and I need to right align the buttons.  The problem is that when I use `float: right`, the submit element is taken out of the normal document flow.  This means the form's height is reduced and it's bottom border then interferes with the button.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left-col {
            width: 290px;
        }
        #loginForm {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }   
        #submit {
            /* float: right; */
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left-col">
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form id="user-login-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
                <label for="email" class="required">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
                <label for="password" class="required">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The forms are generated programatically (using Zend_Form) so I am hoping to avoid hacks that require additional elements (such as paragraphs with clear: both).

Hopefully this will be a simple question for a CSS guru!

Thanks...

Comment: all theses elements are inline so i would assume the submit would be in the far right.

Comment: Using float:right; in FF and chrome did not change the size of the form for me.  Can you be more specific about what is happening that you wish to change or prevent?

Comment: Where are you wanting the labels in relation to the textboxes?

Comment: @Ibu: these elements do not show up as inline when I run this code.

Comment: here is a solution : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tm8bY/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the CSS `:after` pseudoelement to clear the container, without adding any extra HTML markup.

You would add something like this to your CSS:

```
#loginForm:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or to the `form` element, whichever you deem more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks jblasco, that's a hot tip

Answer (score 4):

To make the form (or any element) expand to contain internal floats, apply the "overflow: auto" style, as per the last paragraph of [10.6.7 of the CCS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#root-height):

> In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is increased to include those edges. Only floats that participate in this block formatting context are taken into account, e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats are not.

According to section 10.6.6. of the same spec, among other things, it applies to:

> Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' does not compute to 'visible' (except if the 'overflow' property's value has been propagated to the viewport).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsFiddle demo I made -- http://jsfiddle.net/tm8bY/1/ -- to show how you should be able to achieve what you want.

Copy of the code used in the demo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left-col {
            width: 290px;
        }
        #loginForm {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }   
        #submit {
            /* float: right; */
        }
        label {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left-col">
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form id="user-login-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
                <label for="email" class="required">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
                <label for="password" class="required">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: right">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>Note: The in-line style I used could be converted to a CSS `class` instead. I also added a rule for `label` so it looks a little more styled.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you want the submit button inside the border then
http://jsfiddle.net/bTp2K/1/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left-col {
            width: 290px;
        }
        #loginForm {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }   
        #submit {
            /* float: right; */
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left-col">
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form id="user-login-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
                <label for="email" class="required">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
                <label for="password" class="required">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
            </div>
                <div style="text-align: right">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[type=submit]{

    margin-left: 121px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 40px;   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;

}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.